# Populate editable PDF form fields with php

Tags: php, tcpdf, fpdf, pdf-form

I've got an existing PDF form that my office has created that has form fields for the user to fill out (electronically) and print.  Before passing it to the user I would like to open the existing PDF and populate as much (if not all) of that data using php.  I've looked into extensions like TCPDF and FPDI, but I'm unable to confirm that what I want to do is even possible by looking at the examples and documentation.  Have any of you done this before?

I did see [TCPDF::setFormDefaultProp](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/classTCPDF.html#a1611451af253619217095e279f52fa52), which looked promising...

Comment: It does look promising. Did you try it?

Comment: No, because I don't know how to open the PDF to work with it...

Comment: Suppose that's because I just read that TCPDF can't open PDFs and use them like I'd like...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pdftk has a [`fill_form`](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-fill-form) command. Since it doesn't have PHP bindings you'll have to install it on your server and invoke it with `exec()` et al but it's pretty easy. To use it you'll have to generate an FDF file, which Pdftk will do given the [`generate_fdf`](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-generate-fdf) command, then plug the desired data into it. You can find some information on FDF files [here](http://www.myown1.com/linux/pdf_formfill.shtml) and some example PHP code [here](http://www.pdfhacks.com/forge_fdf/) and [here](https://github.com/andrewheiss/pdftk-php). In truth I think you could just put the generated FDF file in your PDF script and, given the right escaping, fill the values like you would in any string, then pipe it back into `pdftk fill_form`.

Comment: Just need 2 files : pdftk.exe and libiconv2.dll. It works very fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a commercial product like SetPDF http://www.setasign.com/

Comment: This looks really nice but pricing is $250 to $1600 depending on features you want. So weigh that against the time you'll spend trying to recreate the same functionality.